# node js button and java code action

Tags: java, node.js

Is it possible to call java code inside `node js` button action  ?
I have a web application in `node.js` which include button ( say print) and I want to add action on that button to call java code( Printing code )inside that button action .Is it possible to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You have [node-java](https://github.com/joeferner/node-java) just for that, integrating java code into your nodejs app.